# SQL byte converter function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a function or how would you implement a function that would check the last two characters of a string and convert this string to bytes?

such as '1GB' 
`convert('1GB')` 
`returns` = `1073741824`

It needs to check if it's a MB and TB as well.

Thank you!

Comment: `CASE RIGHT([column], 2) WHEN 'KB' THEN 1024. WHEN 'MB' THEN 1024. * 1024. WHEN 'GB' THEN ...` Adding the conversion for the part before the unit and making sure the calculation lines up is left as an exercise.

Comment: `1048576 * case right(s, 2) when 'mb' then 1 when 'gb' then 1024 when 'tb' then 1024 * 1024 end * cast(left(s, len(s) - 2) as int)` Make sure you're dealing with integers or adjust accordingly.

Comment: if you could post the code that would be appreciated! I am very new to SQL and am still trying to learn. Thank you!

Comment: `power(1024, case lower(right(s, 2)) when 'mb' then 1 when 'gb' then 2 when 'tb' then 3 end) * cast(left(s, len(s) - 2) as int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would implement such a function - as a table valued function which you can then use via a correlated subquery, join or apply:

```
create or alter function ValueToBytes(@input varchar(10))
returns table as

return
select Try_Convert(bigint,Replace(v.input,v.ext,'')) * multi [Value]
from (select @input input,Right(@input,2) ext)v
join (
    select ext, multi
    from (values
      ('KB',Power(Convert(bigint,1024),1)),
      ('MB',Power(convert(bigint,1024),2)),
      ('GB',Power(convert(bigint,1024),3)),
      ('TB',Power(convert(bigint,1024),4)),
      ('PB',Power(convert(bigint,1024),5)),
      ('EB',Power(convert(bigint,1024),6))
    )m(ext,multi)
)m on m.ext=v.ext
```

Simple usage:

```
select * from ValueToBytes('10GB')
select * from ValueToBytes('5MB')
```

Comment: Just for completeness, I would add petabytes: 1125899906842624, exabytes: 1152921504606846976  :)  +1

Comment: For completeness then why not. Using `power` makes it a little easier - I guess an exercise for the reader would be to add some validation for something like '8EB' :)